# How to combine change `key: foo`, `key: bar`, `key: baz` to `key: foo bar baz`?

Tags: text-editing

To clarify this is what I'd like to do:

Text Before:

```
key: foo
key: bar
key: baz
```

Text After:

```
key: foo bar baz
```

Wondering if anyone has a good  technique for this type of operation (simpler the better). Suspect it might be possible with `replace-regexp` and some back reference trickery - been trying to figure out a way but no inspiration has hit yet :)

Comment: What would you do manually? Just do that, recording what you do as a keyboard macro.

Comment: Manually, just replace `<newline>key:` with an empty string?

Comment: The problem with the manual methods is that I have a large number of these - - with different keys and number of entries. I was looking for a more programmatic option like the function suggested by xuchunyang@. Agree though for quick edits these work too

Comment: I suggest that the question text be edited to provide these clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a command to merge two lines, if these two lines share a common prefix, don't duplicate it

```
(defun my-merge-two-lines ()
  "Merge the next line into the current line."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let (current-line next-line prefix)
      (setq current-line
            (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
      (kill-whole-line)
      (setq next-line
            (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
      (kill-whole-line)
      (setq prefix (fill-common-string-prefix current-line next-line))
      (insert
       (concat current-line " " (substring next-line (length prefix)) "\n")))))
```

For example, assuming the point is on the first line

```
key: foo
key: bar
key: baz
```

run the above command twice, the text becomes

```
key: foo bar baz
```

---

If you like the idea, you can simply use the builtin <kbd>M-^</kbd> (`delete-indentation`/`join-line`), note that you need manually set the prefix to `"key: "` via <kbd>C-x .</kbd> (`set-fill-prefix`).

Comment: Thanks for the two excellent suggestions!